# How to verify SNS message authenticity in spring aws cloud SNS http end point

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I am writing an SNS http end point using Spring [AWS cloud](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html). I cannot see anything regarding verifying the message signature in the [doc](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_annotation_driven_http_notification_endpoint). How Can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very old question, but maybe somebody have problem with it.

Methodology is quite simple. U need to create InputStream from SignatureUrl and generate certificate based on this InputStream

```
InputStream inStream = url.openStream();
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
inStream.close();
```

Next You need to use Signature. Get instance of SHA1withRSA, get Your public key from cert that is generated by You and update Signature with data from Your message

```
 Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
 sig.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
 sig.update(getMessageBytesToSign(msg));
 return sig.verify(Base64.decodeBase64(msg.getSignature()));
```

You can find full example on [AmazonDoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-example-code-endpoint-java-servlet.html)

When You create this methods just use it as static utils for Your service which recive messages from SNS eg.

```
VerifySNS.isMessageSignatureValid(msg);
```

msg attribute is SNSTopic message.